# 'You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'Booking'.' error when removing a PKFK value in a SQL database in C#

Tags: sql-server, c#

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'Booking'.'
```

My sub-routine to get rid of the booking with a given BookingID in the Textbox 'TxbID' is given by:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT BookingID, Occupied FROM Room WHERE Room.BookingID = '" + TxbID.Text + "'";
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Room SET BookingID = '', Occupied = False WHERE Room.BookingID = '" + TxbID.Text + "'";
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Booking WHERE Booking.BookingID = '" + TxbID.Text + "'";
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Occupant WHERE Occupant.CustomerID = '" + CID + "'";
```

My table creation code is:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Occupant(CustomerName VARCHAR, CustomerNumber CHAR(11), CustomerID VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID))";
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Booking(BookingID VARCHAR, DateIn DATE, DateOut DATE, TotalPrice FLOAT, CustomerName VARCHAR, CustomerID VARCHAR, FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Occupant(CustomerID), PRIMARY KEY (BookingID))";
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Room(BookingID VARCHAR, RoomNumber VARCHAR, RoomSize VARCHAR, RoomPrice FLOAT, Occupied BIT, PRIMARY KEY (RoomNumber), FOREIGN KEY(BookingID) REFERENCES Booking(BookingID))";
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'm working on my computer science A-Level project so help is very appreciated.

Edit:

This function only allows number 0-9 to be input so injection shouldn't be an issue here? (The booking ID is an integer)

```
private void TxbID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TxbID.Text, "[^0-9]"))
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
          TxbID.Text = TxbID.Text.Remove(TxbID.Text.Length - 1);
     }
 }
```

And `UPDATE Room SET BookingID = '', Occupied = False WHERE Room.BookingID = '" + TxbID.Text + "'` is where my error occurs.

My goal is to be able to delete a booking from the database by deleting the row from Occupant and Booking. My Room table is filled with the information for each room along with a BookingID which I wanted to set blank when the booking is deleted. How do I go about that?

Comment: Which line of code is specifically throwing the exception?

Comment: Aside to the actual question, but this sample code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

Comment: I've edited my post^

Answer (score 1):

> `"UPDATE Room SET BookingID = '', Occupied = False WHERE Room.BookingID = '" + TxbID.Text + "'";`

You don't have a Booking record with a BookingID of `''`. I suspect you have your relationship the wrong way round; a Booking should have a RoomID rather than a room having a BookingID, or if you want to persist with the current architecture you should perhaps be setting Room.BookingID null

Please read [this](https://bobby-tables.com/) website, not because it solves your problem, but because you're making the [most grave mistake](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vtech+hack) anyone can make when writing database software, and you need to kick the habit now. (If you did it while working for my company, they'd just fire you)